# How to rollback transactions and continue processing updates?

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I'm trying to wrap my head around transaction management, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I should recover from a transaction rollback and continue committing new transactions.  The code below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
@Stateless
public class MyStatelessBean1 implements MyStatelessLocal1 {

@EJB
private MyStatelessLocal1 myBean1;

@TransationAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public void processObjects(List<Object> objs) {
    // this method just processes the data; no need for a transaction
    for(Object obj : objs) {
        // If the call to process results in the transaction being rolled back,
        // how do I rollback the transaction and continue to iterate over objs?
        this.myBean1.process(obj);
    }
}


@TransationAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void process(Object obj) {
    // do some work with obj that must be in the scope of a transaction
}
}
```

If a transaction rollback occurs in the call to `process(Object obj)`, then an exception is thrown and the rest of the Objects in `objs` are not iterated over and no updates are committed. If I want to rollback the transactions where an error occurs, but continue to iterate over the `objs` List, how should I go about doing that?  If I just catch the exception like in the code below, is there anything I need to do to make sure the transaction is rolled back?

```
public void processObjects(List<Object> objs) {
    // this method just processes the data; no need for a transaction
    for(Object obj : objs) {
        // If the call to process results in the transaction being rolled back,
        // how do I rollback the transaction and continue to iterate over objs?
        try {
            this.myBean1.process(obj);
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            // Do I need to do anything here to clean up the transaction before continuing to iterate over the objs?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to processObjects are in a (separate) Transaction.
You are catching all `RuntimeException`s, lets divide those exceptions into two groups.

Group one:
`EJBException` or any other exception annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` ->
The container will rollback that exception for you.

Group two:
All other exceptions. (Basically those exceptions that won't be rolledback automatically by the container :( ). -> The transaction won't be rolledback unless you make it so.

To force a rollback you can always `throw new EJBException` ... etc ...

Also, please note that once an Exception annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` is thrown, the container will rollback the current transaction, if there is one (EJB-Beans are in a transaction by default) no matter what you do (catch and ignore for example) if the Bean is annotated with `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` which is default in EJB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  So if any exception annotated with `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` is thrown during the call to `this.myBean1.process(obj);`, the transaction will be rolled back by the container and I can just swallow/log the exception?  Then a new transaction will be created by the container in the next call to `this.myBean1.process(obj);` as we're iterating over the list of `objs`?